# My Create & Edit list forms are rendering using the modern UI although we have customize them using Script Editor web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-form, classic-experience, list-form-web-part

We have migrated 3 custom lists from SP 2013 to classic team site inside SP online, now the 3 lists have the following main settings:-

1. we have customized the list forms (Create & Edit) using Script Editor web parts, as follow:-

[image]

2. for the list settings >> we define to render based on the site settings (which is to use modern UI):-

[image]

so now the expected behaviour is that the list views will render using the modern UI + But when we create/edit the list items the Create & Edit forms will render using the classic experience. Now this is working as expected for 2 lists. but is failing for the third list.. where on the third list the Create & Edit forms will render using the modern UI, although they have customized the forms using script editor web parts.. any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-modern-and-classic-experiences-for-lists-and-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc#bkmk_fallback) lists all features that will automatically switch to the classic experience.

Need to pay attention to this:

Only the first customization listed above will trigger a fallback to classic mode on the form.

[image]

Comment: but is this a new feature, as things was not working in this way

Comment: What did you mean "this is a new feature and not working"?Please remember to update the List ContentType.EditForm property.

Comment: what i mean is that previously if we add a script editor web part to the add/edit list forms , then this will force the list forms to render in classic mode, and we did not need to manually define the  ContentType.EditForm property